# td data not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am  new  to Html designing. There is a small section of page that I have to design using html and CSS.

[image: This is the part that I am working on currently]

I have the back ground image with the image of login button. How to develop the Html of this so that it looks the same form in the attached picture.

Till now I have tried this but it is looking distorted:

```
<div class="dvEmployee">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <span class="EmployeeLable">Enter your employee number to vote </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmpID" ValidationGroup="vdLog" CssClass="input"
                    Height="49px" Width="161px" /><br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfgEmp" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vdLog" ControlToValidate="txtEmpID"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter employee number!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" Text="" CssClass="lblError"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/log_in_button.png" ValidationGroup="vdLog"
                    AlternateText="Log In" OnClick="imgBtn_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Css classes that I have made:

```
.dvEmployee
{
    background-image: url('images/log_in_window.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 466px;
    height: 206px;
    position: relative; /* padding: 100px 30px;*/
    margin: 180px 107px;
    z-index: 2000px;
}

.lblError
{
    font: Arial Regular 12pt #000000;
}

.EmployeeLable
{
    font-family: Arial regular;
    font-size: 29pt;
    color: #404040;
    line-height: 17px;
}
```

Just to give all, following image is how it is currently looking:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I definetely use divs instead of tables for this kind of work

Comment: @MateiMihai i am fine with div based structure too, but i don't have much of an expertise with div. can you post the div based structure for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this srtuctuer :

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <span class="EmployeeLable">Enter your employee number to vote </span>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="center">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmpID" ValidationGroup="vdLog" CssClass="input"
                     Height="49px" Width="161px" /><br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfgEmp" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vdLog" ControlToValidate="txtEmpID"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter employee number!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" Text="" CssClass="lblError"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/log_in_button.png" ValidationGroup="vdLog"
                            AlternateText="Log In" OnClick="imgBtn_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css :

```
.center{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: after making the colspan change,  the text has came in a line but still it is starting out from the box.

Comment: which box?this table tag is for main box,

Comment: I have updated the image, you will see the text is looking left aligned. also the text box and button are not looking properly aligned.